# Failed to recognize hard drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

I'm trying to backup a WD My passport external hdd (2TB). I couldn't find my hdd in file explorer(windows 10), so I checked disk management, which showed "The request failed due to a fatal device hardware error". Also, when I used diskpart to check the partitions, it showed "there are no partitions on this disk to show"

Here's what I tried so far on windows10:

1) Checked the SMART attributes using the cmd wmic diskdrive get status. The status showed OK

2) Checked the status of the hdd through device manager. The device status reads "This device is working properly". I also tried updating the driver, but I already had the latest driver.

3) Used testDisk to try and recover partitions, but it was unable to find any

4) Used EaseUS Data recovery wizard, but it found 0 files

5) Used EaseUS Partition Master, but it was unable to fix the partition.

I gave up on using windows and tried recovering the files on Linux. But after inserting the hard drive and typing the cmd dmesg, I see this as output:

Wrong diagnostic page; asked for 1 got 8;
Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1;
Failed to bind enclosure -19

Does anyone know what I can do from here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have already done effectively everything I might recommend for enthusiast level data recovery, except removing the disk itself from the enclosure and connecting to it directly, to bypass the USB components. I hope its just a USB connector failure, because otherwise, it gets really messy from there, and you (and me and most of humanity) are unlikely to get a positive result.

Answer (score 0):

First, use it in a USB 3.0 port or a powered hub, since it requires 750 mA power.If the data is worth the co$t, you could [try commercial data recovery](https://outsourcedatarecovery.com/wd20nmvw-11w68s0-repair/).

If not worth commercial repair, you [might open the external drive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnNDSID1rJA), remove the HDD (WD20NMVW) and [try to repair the PCB or contacts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tgud0MsqClM). Id does not seem that the HDD can be removed from the PCB and put in another enclosure, though.

if you're lucky, there might be a loose connection, a PCB trace might have broken, or a controller might have failed.